# How to Add scroll bars to crystal report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

My asp.net web form have a crystal report. when load, crystal report page going to out of webform boundaries. i want to get report actual size as webform. can i add scrollbar to crystal report viewer?

Comment: consider adding more information in your question

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Crystal Reports in years but I seem to remember a property or setting someplace that controls the report size. Look for that.

If you can't find it, try placing the report viewer control inside a div with scrollbars.
HTH